# Microsoft Excel 2003 formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I am trying to make a formula most of it works this is what I have so far `=100%-(D62/C62)` this part is great, but if `D62=0` I want it to stay 0.  How do I add to this formula to work?

Answer (score 8):

How about an If/then to check the value of D62?

```
=IF(D62=0,0,100%-(D62/C62))
```

Comment: @cris please mark it as the answer then. :)